# box2d max polygon vertices

Tags: box2d, polygon

i am using box2d for physics in a game i am developing. The problem is i have a sprite which need precise collision, so i have created a outline of the sprite using one polygon.

The problem is that box2d supports only max 8 vertices per polygon. Is there a way in box2d to use a polygon with more than 8 vertices? Do i have to split the polygon into triangles? Is there any other way of doing this? I have considered using chained edges but they don't collide with other chains..

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need a little more than 8 you could change the value of b2_maxPolygonVertices in the b2Settings.h file. If you need a lot more you should really keep it at 8 and split the shape into smaller polygons (you don't need to split into triangles unless the shape is concave).